# Why is this relation not transitive but R = {(3,4)} is ?

Tags: relations

While studying relations, I came across a strange question.

Set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ on which the relation
$R=\{(2,4),(4,3),(2,3),(4,1)\}$ is defined. It is said in the answer that the relation is not transitive. I am not able to find out why is it so.

Let $R=\{(3,4)\}$. This is said to be transitive in the answer.

Can anyone give proper reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $R$ is *transitive* if $(a,b),(b,c)\in R\Rightarrow (a,c)\in R$.

Here, you have that $(2,4),(4,1)\in R$, but $(2,1)\not\in R$, so $R$ is not transitive.

Comment: oh.. My mistake. Thanks for the answer. I understood it. Can you explain me the second one too ?

Comment: Have you thought about it ? Since you have only one element, the relation is trivially transitive: no such couples $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)\in R$ exists, so you have nothing to check.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya:  The second one is transitive "by vacuity" there are no pairs in $R$ of the form $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$. Since the premise of the implication is always false, the implication itself is always true.

Comment: Understood it. Thank you. Then i can also call it antisymmetric right?.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya Right!

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is a transitive relation if for every $a,b,c\in A$ **if** $(a,b), (b,c)\in R$ **then** $(a,c)\in R$.

As others have said, in the first relation $(2,4),(4,1)\in R$ but $(2,1)\notin R$. This proves that $R$ is not transitive.

This is because in order to prove $R$ is not transitive we need to find three elements $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$ such that $(a,c)\notin R$.

However in the case $R=\{(3,4)\}$ there is **only** one pair of elements. There is no possible counterexample to transitivity, and so it holds *vacuously*.

Answer (score 0):

$(2,4)$ and $(4, 1)$ are in the relation, but $(2, 1)$ is not, and so the relation cannot be transitive.

Comment: What about R={(3,4)}. Why it is transitive?

Answer (score 0):

it is transitive if all possible combination are transitive, if R={(3,4)} ok but (2,1)∉R it still can't be transitive

Comment: but if (4,1) appear, (1,2)didn't, no matter (2,4) appear, it still ok

Comment: ∀x∀y ∀z[(x,y) ∊R ∧ (y,z) ∊ R ⟶ (x,z) ∊ R ] is transitive fomular, so if (x,y) ∊R, but (y,z) ∉ R , first argument is False, no matter the second argument (x,z) ∊ R is true or false, the final result it still true